# How to use escape character in replace function when replacing semi-colon in VB

Tags: vb.net, escaping

Okay so I was helped earlier with my program question and found out that """" is how you make " become another variable in the function:

```
Robert = Replace(Robert.ToLower, """", "A")
```

So now I am also trying to work with other keys like the semi-colon.  I put it in the function like this:

```
Robert = Replace(Robert.ToLower, "char(59)", "B")
```

I also tried to insert ; in place of char(59) with \ in front of it as an escape key, none of this worked.  It still just gives me a ; when I type a ;.  Can someone please help me with this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Robert = Replace(Robert.ToLower, chr(59), "B")
```

Comment: Thx guys!  I clicked check mark... I don't know what it means though.  I figured he has more points than you so I gave you check :)  I appreciate it guys!

Comment: You can also use:  Robert = Robert.ToLower.Replace(chr(59),"B")

Answer (score 0):

```
Robert = Replace(Robert.ToLower, chr$(59), "B")
```

Comment: I intentionally left out the $ there, it's just a leftover from older basic dialects.

Comment: without the $ it's a variant, and will involve an implicit cast to string